# Calling Windows applications Button click event from web application

Tags: asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0

We have a requirement of calling windows applications button click event from web application.The scenario is, currently we are launching our web site from windows application. In web application there is link. When we click on the link we must call our parent windows applications button click event. I want to confirm whether it is possible in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) to accomplish such requirement.

Please answer ASAP. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may host wcf-service into your win application. After web-click you sending request to wcf-service and wcf-service doing work in context win application.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But i don't get you actually. can you please elaborate it more?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx
You create host in managed win application. The service listen some URI and wait request. After request win application doing work that you need. You can send request from IIS when click event raise aspx-page.